# Error: [FBSDKSettings appID] must be specified for batch requests

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FBSDKGraphRequestConnection: [FBSDKSettings appID] must be specified for batch requests'
```

I got this error when trying to run 2 batch requests. The code below shows what I have done. How can I solve this problem ?

```
   let requestForOSP =
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: FacebookParameters.OSP,
                          parameters: [ nil ],
                          httpMethod: "GET")

    let requestForMSA =
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: FacebookParameters.MSA,
                           parameters: [ nil ],
                          httpMethod: "GET")



   let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()

    connection.add(requestForOSP, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

   // DO Stuff

  }


    connection.add(requestForMSA, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

   // DO Other Stuff

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

1. I had to create a Facebook app Here:  https://developers.facebook.com/apps/,
2. Select iOS idk,
3. take the app number
4. place it in Xcode's plist file